# How to define composite types withinpackages with PostgreSql

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-migration

I have involved with migration process Oracle to PostgreSql. Ora2pg converted lots of procedures, packages in proper way. But there are some packages that not included.

- Packages with functions are created successfully.
- Problem with packages are containing composite type vatiables.

```
create or replace PACKAGE main_table
AS
    TYPE t_mainStruct IS RECORD (
                     key  VARCHAR2(900),
                     value        VARCHAR2(900)
                     );
   TYPE t_mainTable IS TABLE OF t_mainStruct INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
end;
```

---

My main problem is that the variable not reachable from a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_main_table (p_inMain text) RETURNS MAIN_TABLE.T_MAINTABLE AS $body$
DECLARE


  -- Variables
   v_Mains              parm_table.t_ParmTable;

.
.
.

BEGIN
.
..
...
 v_Mains[id].key := substr(v_InParmWork,1,v_ParseLoc - 1);
```

The error is :

**Unable to resolve column 'key'more**

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's going on with the little bit of code you posted, but is your type mimicking a table that already exists?  If so, postgres has already implicitly created a type with the same name as that table.  Your function could just return SETOF tablename.

Comment: The package is defined in Oracle side and have global variables. I could not reach these variables in function on PostgreSql, because the variable in package is not defined. How can I perform it ?

Comment: Postgres has neither packages nor global variables.  Some conversion tools create schemas to simulate packages, but you'll need to store your variable in a table or refactor your functions.